# Differential equation of $F(y,y',y'') = 0$ type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying to solve the deferential equations of $F(y,y',y'') = 0$ type by using the example of the solution for the equation: $$(1 + yy')y'' = (1 + (y')^2)y'$$
In the example one uses the substitutions $ y'=p(y) $ and $ y'' = p \cdot p'$. The result of the substitutions is:
$$p' = \frac {1+p^2}{1+py} $$
Then one uses the substitutions $ p' = \frac {1}{y'} $  to rewrite the equation like this:
$$ y' = \frac {1 +py}{1 + p^2} $$
The solution's next steps are absolutely clear but I can't understand how the substitution $ p' = \frac {1}{y'} $ was worked out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a standard trick, Instead of considering $p$ as a function of $y$, consider $y$ as a function of $p$. Then$$
p'=\frac{dp}{dy}=\frac{1}{dy/dp}=\frac{1}{y'}.
$$

Comment: $y(x)=C$ is one solution

Comment: @Julian Aguirre: So it is understood that the same primes employed denote no more differentiation  with respect to x , but with respect to p?

Comment: $p'$ means differentiation of $p$ with respect to $y$, and $y'$ differentiation of $y$ with respect to $p$. It may not be the best of notations, but it is useful.